# Problema con Webservice en GeneXus 17

Tags: webservice, genexus

Espero puedan ayudarme con un problema que estoy teniendo al crear WebServices con Genexus 17, Java 8 y Tomcat 9.

Tengo una KB que está funcionando perfectamente en mi equipo (localhost). La misma tiene WorkWithPlus y GAM.

Ahora bien, desde esa KB tengo que exponer un ws que recibe una serie de parámetros y devuelve 3 SDT. Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema se da cuando intento obtener el wsdl del ws, me da error "404 no se ha encontrado: Invalid Request". Verifiqué en el Tomcat y todos los objetos están allí, incluso lo bajé y volví a subir y da lo mismo.
Hasta donde puedo ver tengo todo correctamente bien configurado, pero obviamente algo está mal y no me doy cuenta.

A nivel del modelo lo que cambié fueron las propiedades "Use Native Soap" a YES porque de otra forma siempre me daba error en los parámetros y la otra fue "Expose descriptive metadata" a YES para intentar que me muestre la metadata del wsdl pero tampoco funcionó (y no estoy seguro incluso que esa propiedad sirva para eso).
Por otro lado, a nivel del objeto puse que es main y SOAP, el resto lo dejé como estaba.

¿A alguien le ha sucedido esto? ¿Alguien sabe como configurar el modelo y objeto para que el ws funcione correctamente?
El resto de la aplicación web está funcionando perfecto, pero esto no.
Desde ya agradecería mucho lo que puedan ayudarme

Saludos

Sergio Guichón
Montevideo - Uruguay

---

Lo que estoy preguntando es como debo configurar el modelo y el objeto para que funcione.
El modelo lo tengo configurado casi sin cambios respecto a lo que indica GeneXus, y así funcionan perfectamente todos los objetos web (todo el sitio).
Ahora bien, tengo que exponer un webservice que recibe algunos valores y devuelve 3 SDT con datos.
Este webservice lo configuré como Main y SOAP (y no toqué nada más).
Lo genero y todo bien, veo los objetos en el Tomcat pero al ejecutarlo ahora me está diciendo el siguiente error:
Estado HTTP 404 – No encontrado

Tipo Informe de estado

mensaje El recurso requerido [/SeguridadJavaEnvironment/ws/com.seguridad.aloginappbeneficios] no se encuentra disponible

Descripción El recurso requerido no está disponible.

Pero como decía, si miro en el Tomcat el objeto está disponible. Ya bajé y volví a subir el Tomcat por las dudas que el mismo no hubiera registrado las classes pero tampoco.

Este procedimiento lo he hecho con versiones anteriores de GeneXus (Evolution 2 y 3) y funcionaba perfectamente así, pero ahora no logro hacer que ejecute ni siquiera para poder ver el wsdl

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.